# C++ Synchronization timed wait

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, synchronization

I have a multithreaded c++ application. I want to flag an object with a busy/free state, such as:

- Threads can toggle the object's state
- Threads must have exclusive access to certain public member functions at any time (while other public member functions don't need synchronization)
- If the object is busy, a thread can choose to wait either infinitely or for a defined period until the object becomes free.

I implemented the requirements below, is there a better way to do it?

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>  
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

std::mutex m_Mutex;
std::condition_variable m_ConditionVariable;
std::atomic_flag m_BusyFlag;

const int TRY_LOCK_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 1;

bool IsFree() { return !m_BusyFlag.test_and_set(); }

bool LockSeqNum(bool timed_wait)
{
    std::cout <<" TRY LockSeqNum, thread= " << std::this_thread::get_id() << endl;
    bool success = true;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(m_Mutex);
    if (m_BusyFlag.test_and_set())
    {
        if (timed_wait)
            success = !m_ConditionVariable.wait_for(lck, std::chrono::milliseconds(TRY_LOCK_TIMEOUT_MILLIS), [] { return IsFree(); });
        else
            m_ConditionVariable.wait(lck, [] { return IsFree(); });
    }

    std::cout << "LockSeqNum " << success << "  thread = " << std::this_thread::get_id() << endl;
    return success;
}

void UnlockSeqNum()
{
    std::cout << " UNLockSeqNum, thread= " << std::this_thread::get_id() << endl;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(m_Mutex);
    m_BusyFlag.clear();
    m_ConditionVariable.notify_one();
}
```

Comment: Why `atomic_flag` and not `bool`?

Comment: use you can use bool as well, I chose atomic_flag because i only need two methods: test_and_set and clear. But you can do the same with a bool since the lock is synchronizing access to it.

Comment: In what way does your code fail to do what you want it to do?  "Is there a better way" is better suited to code review.  I could point out a whole pile of stuff I wouldn't do, ranging from use of global variables, constants, pointless atomics, I don't like that FunctionNamingConvention, DRY failure, etc: but without a description of why your code fails, I don't know which is because you where making a MCVE or whatever.

Comment: You are right. This is more of a code review, as the code works fine. The use of global variables is just a simplification to post the code here as it is part of a larger component. I was hoping more for a review of the data structures and the synchronization logic. Basically, what I am asking for is whether there is a simpler way to achieve the requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allow outer of `IsFree()`, code is fine. Otherwise, as Yakk pointed in comments, it is sufficient to declare `m_BusyFlag` as simple boolean. `atomic_flag` is overhead there as variable is always accessed under the mutex.

You have the minimal tools, needed for use conditional wait: conditional variable, mutex and normal variable for wait its state. So, the simpler implementation(simple locking) is possible only if `UnlockSeqNum` is required to be called by the thread, which have called LockSeqNum before.